# How to run a database search inside template in django

Tags: python, django, templates

I am new and trying to display the image of user after he logs in. I am using the django user model which is a Foreign key to my extended user model which is called Consumer. I am using auth.views to authenticate the user and generate view. I able to get the username but not able to retrieve the image URL as I am not able get the Consumer instance. Where and how can I extract the Consumer detail for the logged in user without writing my own authentication code.

Please help. Please see my code below

Models.py

```
class Consumer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    cimage = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

urls.py

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

screen.html

Comment: `<img src="{{ request.user.consumer.cimage.url }}" />` will display the consumer's image in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting the username via `{{ user.username }}` you can just do the same thing to get to the consumer: `{{ user.consumer.cimage }}`.

Comment: I had tried this but it did not work earlier as I was making a mistake. But after your confirmation I tried again and it works. Thanks a ton.